# Add UserType To JWT Token IN laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt

**How Can I Bind  userType with jwt token**??
because in the   frontend  needs to do some operations with type of user(hide some menus if userType is different)

in laravel.. Does it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The way Laravel (and you most likely using https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth), is that the JWT should probably not carry user types or really other kind of user information than maybe a name or an id. After the token is generated, you are supposed to query another endpoint that will return the user information that you are looking for.

So essentially, what you want is 2 routes, let's say:

```
POST /auth/login
POST /auth/me
```

To the first route, you are supposed to provide the username and password, to which you'll get a token if credentials are correct. Then, you take the token you were just given, and call the second endpoint, which will return all user information you might want or need. You don't specify which kind of frontend you are using, but here's an example with Nuxt.js's Auth module: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/laravel-jwt/